# Accessing internal Macintosh HD with Boot Camp Windows To Go install on external drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, startup

I've installed a bootable Windows 10 (Windows To Go) install on an external SSD with Boot Camp drivers. Accessing the internal drive while running Windows To Go [is not recommended by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-frequently-asked-questions#wtg-faq-san4), but they specifically mention problems with corruption when the internal drive has Windows 7 or earlier installed and was left hibernating.

I have macOS Big Sur installed on my internal drive, and I find it inconvenient that I can't access the files on my internal drive and I want to try mounting the drive -- has anyone tried this? Does anyone foresee any potential problems with doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Corruption can only occur if the internal drive is mounted read/write. I don't use Boot Camp myself, but I've read that Boot Camp now includes an APFS driver, so I guess you should be able to mount the internal drive read-only.

Comment: I was not aware Windows can mount APFS volumes with using some third party tools. Assuming you are not using a third party tool and do not have Windows installed on the internal drive, then what volumes did you wish to mount? Would you want read-only or read/write access?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I only have Big Sur installed on the internal drive. I wish to mount the internal drive which only contains a single partition with a Big Sur install when I boot into Windows 10 on the external drive. I would prefer read/write access to the internal drive but I'm also fine with read-only, since internal Big Sur can easily access the files on the external Windows install.